# How to remove parent array index from array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove parent array index in array.

Following is my array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 296
                    [username] => David0123
                    [profile_slug] => david-love


                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 297
                    [username] => Anne_wils
                    [profile_slug] => anne-chase


                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 300
                    [username] => malina001
                    [profile_slug] => malina-reid


                )

        )

)
```

And I want like this way..

```
Array(    
     [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 296
                [username] => David0123
                [profile_slug] => david-love
       )    
     [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 297
                [username] => Anne_wils
                [profile_slug] => anne-chase
            )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 300
            [username] => malina001
            [profile_slug] => malina-reid
        )
)
```

I used following script for it but not work.

```
$myMainArray = json_decode(json_encode($allEscorts),true);
$i=0;
foreach( array_values($myMainArray) as $k=> $val){
            echo $val[$i]['id'];    
            $i++;
}
```

I want to display data each element but first i have to remove parent array indexes.

Comment: How do you generate the first array, can you fix this rather than run a second process to fix it?

Comment: @NigelRen, First array it's comes from dynamic and i could not paste whole the code here for first array because first array's code is too large.

Comment: Have a look for yourself, when assigning the values to the main array, does it wrap the new data in another level of array that you can remove?

Comment: Just noticed the `json_decode(json_encode())` which may hint at you are using XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_map` to pull values up one level

```
$myMainArray = json_decode(json_encode($allEscorts),true);

$myMainArray = array_map(function($el) {
    return $el[0];
}, $myMainArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the first array could be generate as you wish.
If not you can use array_map to get the first index from the inner-array.

for example:

```
$result = array_map(function($item){
            return $item[0]; // always return the first array-index
        }, $first_array);
```